# Excel VBA Macro to concatinate two columns using column header id name

Tags: vba, excel

I am really new in writing Excel macros through VBA. I want to concatenate two columns in my Excel worksheet. I have data in columns A, B & C and I want to concatenate B & C column to D column. This is the code I wrote:

```
Sub FINAL()
'
' FINAL Macro
'    
'    
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SO::LI"
Range("D3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&""::""&RC[-1]"
Range("D3").Select

     Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D3:D" & lastRow)
End Sub
```

This works fine. But This works only when my data is in columns A, B & C.
When the data is in different columns, such as E, F & G, this does not work.

So what I want is to find the column using column header name and concatenate data.

```
Style   S/O     L/I   
392389  265146   40
558570  300285   10
558570  300285   20
```

After concatenation:

```
Style   S/O    L/I       SO::LI
392389  265146  40  265146::40
558570  300285  10  300285::10
558570  300285  20  300285::20
```

Comment: Also I propse you may want to edit the title of this question - you already know how to fill the column with concatenated values, what you're really asking here is how to identify a certain column header and then use that id as to fill the same column.

Comment: I have changed the question. Thanks for your feedback. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a column header by using the worksheet MATCH function inside VBA, here I'll put it in to a variable called `c1`

`c1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("S/O", Range("1:1"), 0)`

It's best to wrap this identification in a potential error handler, because if there IS no match then you'll get a run-time error

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("1:1"), "S/O") > 0 Then
    c1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("S/O", Range("1:1"), 0)
Else
    MsgBox ("Couldn't find ""S/O"" header!")
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Here it uses the worksheet function COUNTIF to make sure there is at least one instance of "S/O" - if there isn't then the subroutine ends.

After that, you've identified your S/O column so can carry on with the rest of the code as usual - if you assume the columns are always consecutive then you can use `c1` + 1 to mean "L/I" column and `c1 + 2` to mean the CONCAT column

Below is a fully working version of the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim c1 As Long
Dim lastRow As Long

' If instance of "S/O" exists then find the column number else show error message and end
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("1:1"), "S/O") > 0 Then
    c1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("S/O", Range("1:1"), 0)
Else
    MsgBox ("Couldn't find ""S/O"" header!")
    Exit Sub
End If

' Get last row for formula based on the "S/O" column header in c1
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, c1).End(xlUp).Row

' add 2 to c1 to make the c1 variable contain column number for SO::LI
c1 = c1 + 2

' use FormulaR1C1 as usual to flood the whole column from row 2 to lastRow
Range(Cells(2, c1).Address, Cells(lastRow, c1).Address).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&""::""&RC[-1]"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @jamheadart .. Sorry for the late reply. I was bit busy this week. I tried this. .And it has worked. Cheers!

Comment: Better late than never :D Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use FormulaR1C1 instead is useful

```
Sub mergeColumn()
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim tr As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        On Error Resume Next
        col = Rows(1).Find(What:="S/O").Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        If col <> 0 Then ' if not found, it goes to 0
            tr = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
            Range(Cells(1, col + 2), Cells(tr, col + 2)).Value = "=RC[-2] & ""::"" & RC[-1]"
        End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This does not answer his question. He's asking how to identify a column location based on the header: "When the data is in different columns, such as E, F & G, this does not work. So what I want is to find the column using column header name and concatenate data." Also, it uses a loop to fill a column which is much slower than filling with an Excel formula in one go, particularly if he has a lot of rows

Comment: Thanks for mention me, I didn't read carefully about his question then. So, I edit my answer now.

Comment: Thanks all for your support. All of this helped me to solve my problem..Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You may give this a try...

The code will find the headers in row2 and concatenate the columns.

```
Sub Final()
Dim FirstCell As Range, SecondCell As Range
Dim lr As Long, r As Long, c As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Assuming that the Row2 is the Header Row, if not change it.
Set FirstCell = Rows(2).Find("S/O")
If FirstCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "A column with the header S/O was not found.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

Set SecondCell = Rows(2).Find("L/I")
If SecondCell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "A column with the header L/I was not found.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

r = FirstCell.Row + 1
c = SecondCell.Column + 1

Set FirstCell = FirstCell.Offset(1)
Set SecondCell = SecondCell.Offset(1)


lr = Cells(Rows.Count, SecondCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Columns(c).Insert

Range(Cells(r, c), Cells(lr, c)).Formula = "=" & FirstCell.Address(0, 0) & "&""::""&" & SecondCell.Address(0, 0) & ""
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sktneer. I will try this code and let you know. I was bit busy this week.Cheers!!

Comment: @PhilSmith No issues. Try it as per your convenience.